# Obfuscate single package with all dependencies

Tags: obfuscation, proguard

I would like to obfuscate a single package and its all dependent classes and non-java resources files.

Can anybody let me know if this is possible using proguard.
if yes how we can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can preserve all classes (with their fields and methods) outside of the package:

```
-keep class !mysinglepackage.** { *; }
```

Note that obfuscating just a single package generally isn't very effective, since so much of the code is being preserved.